# How can I get Google Charts to display multiple colors in a scatter chart?

Tags: google-visualization, scatter

I would like to display multiple colors (and potentially shapes and sizes) of data points in a Google Chart scatter chart. Does anyone have an example of how to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered my own question after waiting SECONDS for an answer here :-)

You can indeed have different colors for different data elements. For example:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x200&cht=s&chd=t:1,2,3|6,5,4&chds=1,3,0,10&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|0|1|2|1:|0|10&chm=d,ff0000,0,0,8,0|a,ff8080,0,1,42,0|c,ffff00,0,2,16,0

It's the chm= that does the magic. I was trying to have multiple chm= statements. You need to have just one, but with multiple descriptions separated by vertical bars.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! I would not have thought of using the chm that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use one dataset in a scatter plot, thus only one color.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/#scatter_plot

*From the API description:*

> Scatter plots use multiple data sets differently than other chart types. You can only show one data set in a scatter plot.

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively fake a multi-color scatter plot by using a line plot with white lines and colored [shape markers](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/#shape_markers2) at the points you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example: [twitter charts](http://www.xefer.com/twitter/gruber).  I'm hoping to do the same thing.  Need to find out how to do the concentric circles.